# Adding input rows using jQuery clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Background:

I've got a set of input elements form invoice item details. I want a user to be able to add rows of input fields for each additional item.

#### Input Markup

```
<div class="input-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item_name">Item:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="item_qty[]" placeholder="Quantity">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="item_price[]" placeholder="Price">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="item_total[]" placeholder="Total">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a button to add an additional item

#### Button Markup

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <a id="add-item" href="#">Add Item</a>
</div>
```

#### Button Javascript

```
$('#add-item').click(function(){
    $('.input-row:first').clone().appendTo('.input-row:last');
})
```

### Problem:

When I click the `add` button the first time, it works fine and adds a row of input fields after the first one, however if I click it again it adds 2 rows and then click it again it adds 4 rows. I realise this may be because the cloned `.input-row` div is being included in the clone, but I'm trying to only copy the first div element using the `:first` selector. Any ideas how to resolve this?

#### Question

How can I ensure only one `div` is appended to the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The jQuery `appendTo` method adds the element into the existing div, meaning when you clone it the second time the div contains two rows of input fields and then the third time will contain 4 rows of input fields.

To overcome this use the `insertAfter()` method

#### Button Javascript

```
$('#add-item').click(function(){
    $('.input-row:first').clone().insertAfter('.input-row:last');
})
```

Comment: Did you post the question for answer yourself :P  :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I agree about the triviality, but isn't this conform to the FAQ style of questions?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie No, I mean that Stack Overflow actually supports this kind of things, i.e. the asker that already knows the answer and posts it immediately after. Unless it's been changed recently.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That was your "especially", actually.

Comment: I worked out that appendTo was the wrong method to be using whilst I was typing the question out. When posting the question SO offers you to also post the answer. Having typed the whole thing out I figured it would be useful to share the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've seen so far is the following jQuery Library:
http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html